# How do I create a pivot table in Pandas where one column is the mean of some values, and the other column is the sum of others?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Basically, how would I create a pivot table that consolidates data, where one of the columns of data it represents is calculated, say, by `likelihood percentage` (0.0 - 1.0) by taking the mean, and another is calculated by `number ordered` which sums all of them?

Right now I can specify `values=...` to indicate what should make up one of the two, but then when I specify the `aggfunc=...` I don't know how the two interoperate.

In my head I'd specify two values for `values=...` (likelihood percentage and number ordered) and two values for `aggfunc=...`, but this does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

You could supply to `aggfunc` a dictionary with `column:funtion` (`key:value`) pairs:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['a','a','a'],'m':[1,2,3],'s':[1,2,3]})
print df

   a  m  s
0  a  1  1
1  a  2  2
2  a  3  3

df.pivot_table(index='a', values=['m','s'], aggfunc={'m':pd.Series.mean,'s':sum})

    m  s
a      
a  2  6
```